# JavaScript Stack Execution Issue

Tags: javascript, stack, execution

What is wrong with my function? Why does it print many times instead of one?

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    //click a button dozen times it invokes submit and write message in console.log
    $('button').live('click', function(){ 
       $this = $(this);
       submit($this); //this function maybe push in stack a lot of times 
   });

});

function submit($this){
   img = $this.nextAll(".submit");

   // and when I click on image it must write one time but it writes a lot of times                                   
   img.on('click', function(){                      
      console.log($this.text() + " ----> click"); // 
   });
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what's going on with the code. Can you edit the example and format it properly for syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `live`, it's deprecated, you can write it in this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){ 
       img = $(this).nextAll(".submit");
       img.off('click').on('click', function(){                      
           console.log($(this).text() + " ----> click"); // 
       });
    });
});
```

[**An example using span**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2BUd/4/).

Using `off` unregister the previously added `click` events so it'll fire only once.

### Update:

Following can replace the `live`. You can use the parent wrapper instead of `document`, [read more](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: Thank you! It really helped me. I think problem was in stack execution or deeper, but now I see that I was wrong. Thank you again you saved my time!

Comment: I know that live is deprecated but I have no choise - data dynamically adds to page, so only live can dive into DOM again and again to bind events to my buttons. It works and I don't know better solution.

Comment: ok, I got it) to use on() instead of live() and in future I will avoid many problems

Comment: You don't need to do this in `$(document).ready` if you're only binding to the `document` node.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the issue is with binding the click event to the img each time the function is called, but you never remove it.

```
  // and when I click on image it must write one time but it writes a lot of times                                   
  img.on('click', function(){                      
     console.log($this.text() + " ----> click"); // 
  });
```

I would add the click event outside of the function.

Comment: I have to leave it inside, because I send button's value by clicking on image. So, if I put it outside i loose reference to my utton's object. When I click on button appears image that send value of clicked button. Problem is that I have a lot of buttons with different values, so I have to know on which button I clicked.
I think the problem is much deeper...